# How to expand storage for vagrant box on Windows host

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vagrant

I'm trying to increase the storage space on my vagrant box from 18 GB to 50 GB. The vagrant box is running Ubuntu and the host is Windows 10. There are similar questions on this forum for expanding a VM running on a Mac or Ubuntu host, but none that I could for a Windows host. I went through the steps described in [this](https://thiscodemightwork.wordpress.com/2017/07/25/how-to-expand-vmvagrant-memory-storage) blog post, which involved 
1) using clonehd to convert the machine's .vmdk file to .vmi file,
2) using modifyhd to resize the disk
3) converting it back to a .vmdk file
4) attaching the new disk to the VM.

After these steps were done, the VM Virtualbox Manager showed the disk to have 50 GB of "virtual" storage and 18 GB of "actual" storage, as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhkRs.jpg) shows. Running "df -h" showed exactly the same [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhAVZ.jpg) as before I went through the steps to expand storage (18 GB in "/").

From what I understand, virtual storage means that that the storage space is supposed to expand as data is added to it. But in my case, the virtual disk throws an "insufficient space" error when I try to add more than 18 GB to it. 
What else can I do to set actual storage to 50 GB? I know this probably involves expanding the partition on the Windows host, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you did right from HOST and Vagrant perspective, but now you need to resize disk file system inside Guest OS, in this case Ubuntu root / partition.

By default ext4 filesystem is used, but to check run the command

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
...
```

Then run command to resize Ext4 filesystem to its max size (select tha matching device, e.g. sda1 or another you have):

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Afterwards, run the command:

```
df -h
```

and see the disk free amount.

### In case you have used LVM during install

check the size and available space for physical volumes:

```
pvs
```

It will show something like

```
  PV         VG      Fmt  Attr   PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sda   vg-root lvm2 a--    7.27t   1.08t
```

In this case we know, that LVM volumes are used, and the second number is amount free. 
If PFree is zero, check disk layout, may be you need to resize disk partition at first:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

If PSize is not what you expect, first step you need to resize physical volume to its max size:

```
pvresize /dev/sda
```

Then list volumes with command:

```
lvs
```

And from list you should select name of root volume, in this case it is `/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root` and perform LV resize command:

```
lvresize -rl +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root
```

The `-r` switch should tell LVM to automatically resize undelying filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It doesn't seem to work. When I ran `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root`, I got `The filesystem is already 4854784 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!`. Since 4854784 * 4k = 19 GB, the resize2fs command is not "seeing" the expanded disk. `df -h` also showed no change.

Comment: expanded the answer with LVM case. please check it now

Comment: Thank you for the expanded answer! I ran the commands, but the disk size was still unchanged. Please see the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/dKLtFy1.jpg) with results.

Comment: Can you run "pvs" again? and also "vgs" and "fdisk -l" and show the output?

Comment: This time it worked. The difference was that I resized the partition with GParted before running the `pvresize` and `lvresize` comands, which is something I read about on [other](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661) [forums](https://www.askdavetaylor.com/add-virtual-dvd-drive-to-virtualbox-os/). This [image](https://i.imgur.com/czZZx2t.jpg) shows the results of `pvs` and `lvs` after resizing the partition and before running `pvresize` and `lvresize`. [This](https://i.imgur.com/pyk58uo.jpg) shows the results of resizing commands. `df -h` now shows the expanded space.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen any other tutorials that mention the LVM commands, but it turned out to be a necessary step.

Comment: This instructions worked for me too. I see the new size in all the commands, but in VirtualBox GUI, I'm still seeing "Actual size" being the old one.

Comment: May be some GUI caching issue.. Try close and open again the GUI. Also please check if you have Virtual Box tools or other corresponding guest OS tools installed.